# Crossed homomorphism from cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $\langle x\rangle$ be a cyclic group, and $N$ any group. It is easy to tell when a map $x\mapsto n $ can be extended to a homomorphism: if $o(x)$ is infinite then always; if $o(x)$ is finite then it (map) can be extended to homomorphism only if $o(n)$ divides $o(x)$.

Let $H,N$ be groups with an action of $H$ on $N$ (i.e. homomorphism $H\rightarrow Aut(N)$). 
A map $f$ from a group $H$ to a group $N$ is called *crossed homomorphism* if 
$$f(hk)=f(h)^kf(k)$$
for all $h,k\in H$ where $f(h)^k$ denotes action of $k\in H$ on $f(h)\in N$.

The question is the following natural one:

> given a cyclic group $\langle x\rangle$ with action on $N$, when the map $x\mapsto n$ can be extended to a *crossed homomorphism*?

Comment: How is $kf(h)k^{-1}$ defined if $k\in H$ and $f(h)\in N$?

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to mention action of $H$ on $N$; thanks for pointing it.

Comment: It seems really odd to phrase this in terms of a semidirect product which is never used. What you need is a map from one group to the automorphism group of the other, you don't need to form a semidirect product using this map.

Comment: Is that $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ the automorphism group of the group $N$, or merely the set of all permutations of the set $N$. In other words, does $H$ act on $N$, the group, or $N$, the set? For example, the (left or right) regular action of a group $G$ on "itself", is not a homomorphism into the automorphism group of the group $G$ — the action of any element (non-trivial) $g$ on $G$ under this will *not* be an automorphism of $G$ [for instance, it maps $1_G$ to $g$]. On the other hand, the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation *is* a homomorphism into $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ proper.

Comment: The action is not only permutation, but is *group action on group* (i.e. action preserves binary operation in $N$).